# Plotting non-continuous function

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to plot this function however it should go to infinity every k*pi however it doesn't even resemble the correct plot. Am i doing something wrong?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = center,
    xmin=-2*pi,xmax=2*pi,
    xlabel = $x$,
    ylabel = {$g(x)$},
    xtick={0,1.57,3.14,4.71,6.28,-1.57,-3.14,-4.71,-6.28},
    xticklabels={$0$, $\frac{\pi}{2}$,$\pi$,$\frac{3}{2}\pi$,$2\pi$, $-\frac{\pi}{2}$,$-\pi$,$-\frac{3}{2}\pi$,$-2\pi$},
]
\addplot [
    domain=-10:10, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red,
]
{abs(((sin(deg(x+(pi/4))^2)/(cos(deg((x+(pi)/2)))))};
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This is how it should look

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Welcome! The parentheses were set in a slightly unfortunate way, I added `unbounded coords=jump`, and also adjusted the domain to fit `xmin` and `max`. The result looks like the target screen shot.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = center,
    xmin=-2*pi,xmax=2*pi,
    xlabel = $x$,
    ylabel = {$g(x)$},
    xtick={0,1.57,3.14,4.71,6.28,-1.57,-3.14,-4.71,-6.28},
    xticklabels={$0$, $\frac{\pi}{2}$,$\pi$,$\frac{3}{2}\pi$,$2\pi$, $-\frac{\pi}{2}$,$-\pi$,$-\frac{3}{2}\pi$,$-2\pi$},
    unbounded coords=jump,ymax=5
]
\addplot [
    domain=-2*pi:2*pi, 
    samples=221, 
    color=red,
]
{abs(pow(sin(deg(x+pi/4)),2)/(cos(deg(x+pi/2))))};
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please note also that codes posted here are expected to start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Or with domain from `-10` to `10`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = center,
    xmin=-10,xmax=10,
    xlabel = $x$,
    ylabel = {$g(x)$},
    xtick={0,1.57,3.14,4.71,6.28,-1.57,-3.14,-4.71,-6.28},
    xticklabels={$0$, $\frac{\pi}{2}$,$\pi$,$\frac{3}{2}\pi$,$2\pi$, $-\frac{\pi}{2}$,$-\pi$,$-\frac{3}{2}\pi$,$-2\pi$},
    unbounded coords=jump,ymax=5
]
\addplot [
    domain=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}, 
    samples=401, 
    color=red,
]
{abs(pow(sin(deg(x+pi/4)),2)/(cos(deg(x+pi/2))))};
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that one has to be a bit careful with the choice of `samples`.